# Getting column names using reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, datagridview

I am inserting data from datagridview using entity model in a winForm application. This is my code:

```
using (var context = new EmployeeEntities())
{
  EMPLOYEE emp= new EMPLOYEE ();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
  {
   emp.EMP_ID = (row.Cells[0].Value == null) ? (int?)null : int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
   emp.DEPARTMENT = (row.Cells[1].Value == null) ? string.Empty : row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
   context.EMPLOYEE.AddObject(emp);
   context.SaveChanges();
  }

}
```

Now I want to change the column names using reflection. I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
 EMPLOYEE emp = new EMPLOYEE();
 foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
 {
  foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvLoadTable.Columns)
  {
   column.HeaderText = column.Index.ToString();
  emp.GetType().GetProperty(column.HeaderText).GetValue(entityName, null) = (row.column.Value == null) ? (int?)null : int.Parse(row.column.Value.ToString()); ;

   }
   entityName.EMPLOYEE.AddObject(emp);
   entityName.SaveChanges();}
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: what exactly you want to do?? Table in DB has its own column name right? then what you doing `column.HeaderText = column.Index.ToString();`  what u want to achieve from it?

Comment: Mainly, I just want to get the column names of the table. Here I tried to get the column names from datagridview column header.

Comment: did you mean that you dont want to right a separated line for each column? like `emp.EMP_ID = values` and want to make a generalize one line for all the column?? get the header name and corresponding to that set the properties of entity and save it?

Comment: or you just want to get the column name thats it or any further reason.. you said you tried to get the column name?? but code seems like u r setting the column name.. what exactly u want.. get or set??

Comment: yes, I want to make a generalized line for all columns.

Comment: well its not as easy as u thinking to make one generalize line for all the column.. better to create a separate method which takes the DataGridRow and return your **Employee** entity..

Comment: your question stats you want to take the column name.. and what u asking here is completely different.. if just want to take the column header name of dataGridView you can use the `dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText` which will return header name of the column at index `0` as string